# Only render specific component in a big react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React project which the file structure like below:

| src 
--- index.js
--- | first
--- | --- first.jsx
--- | second 
--- | --- second.jsx

When 'npm start' the React project it will start from the index.js and render the first.jsx and second. jsx.  But How can I  only show second.jsx Component.

Maybe this sounds very simple, however if you really in a big React project with billions of lines of code, I guess that is not easy.

Answer (score 2):

Try [dynamic import](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import):

Before:

```
import { add } from './math';

console.log(add(16, 26));
```

After:

```
import("./math").then(math => {
  console.log(math.add(16, 26));
});
```

That way you can dynamically load only those files that are needed.